# delete sql row automatically after one hour

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 forums
in forum 1 the user insert into table some data and in one of column "result" he insert "processing"
in forum 2 he update that column to "succeed"
what i want to do is if the column stays "processing" (which means the user did not do forum 2 ) for one hour it get automatically deleted after one hour.

Comment: [You're looking for a cron job](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php).

Comment: thanks i think thats it,i have to run a php code that it delete  it  everyone one hour,i will look it up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create MySQL event scheduler.

http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/

Comment: i believe this is better than cron job i will look it up  thanks